# pfSense: How to route traffic out the WAN port?

Tags: dsl-modem, pppoe, pfsense

### Expert version

i want to create a route in pfSense that will send traffic out the ***physical* WAN** port, not the **PPPoE WAN** port. i want to talk to the web-server on my DSL modem; letting me see the current sync rate and SnR margins. The modem doesn't see packets destined for it, because they're being sent through the **PPPoE tunnel**.

---

### Long version

My pfSense router is responsible for setting up the PPPoE connection over DSL to my ISP. When a machine on the LAN wants to sent packets to the internet, the default route sends packets out over the **PPPoE** connection. Those packets, wrapped in a **PPPoE header**, are sent on the ethernet cable to my DSL modem. From there they are sent the ISP, and the internet at large.

```
+----------------------+                  +----------------------+    
|IPv4 header (20 bytes)|    +--------+    |PPPoE header (8 bytes)|    +-----+    {‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾}
|                      |===>|pfSense |===>|IPv4 header (20 bytes)|===>|Modem|===>{Internet}
|                      |    +--------+    |                      |    +-----+    {________}
|                      |                  |                      |
+----------------------+                  +----------------------+
```

i want a way to send a packet out the WAN port itself - not the PPPoE WAN port.

My modem is sitting out there, with a http interface where i can monitor

- connection speed
- signal-to-noise ratio
- bandwidth
- connection time

Whenever i try to set a route for destination of `192.168.2.1` (the IP that the modem will listen to for HTTP requests) to go out the **WAN** port, they instead end up going out the **PPPoE** port.

The difference being that they're wrapped in a PPPoE protocol packet, and the modem isn't being sent the packet, it's being delivered to the ISP.

Given that pfSense has no ability to direct traffic out the physical WAN port: how can i direct traffic out the physical WAN port on pfSense?

---

Here's the exact same question i asked [3 years ago on the pfSense forum](http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/topic,6532.msg37521.html):

My modem has a web interface. It's handy because i can see if it's actually connected or not, line noise, error rates, etc.

If i connect the modem to my destop PC (rather than to the pfSense PC), i can ping and browse the modem's web interface fine. The modem's IP is 192.168.0.254, and listens on port 8080. i also can packet trace the activity from my PC:

**Pinging modem**

```
ARP REQ    Phalanx => Broadcast     192.168.0.98  -?- 192.168.0.254
ARP RESP   Phalanx <= Ovislink_LAN  192.168.0.254 -!- 192.168.0.98
IP/ICMP    Phalanx => Ovislink_LAN  192.168.0.98  =>  192.168.0.254 ECHO
IP/ICMP    Phalanx <= Ovislink_LAN  192.168.0.98  <=  192.168.0.254 ECHOREPLY
```

You can see my machine doing an ARP broadcast, asking for the MAC address of the modem (the Ovislink). The modem responds with its IP, the echo goes out, and i get a reply. Similar detail can be seen when i connect to the web port of the modem:

**Connecting to web port 8080**

```
ARP REQ     Phalanx => Broadcast    192.168.0.98       -?- 192.168.0.254
ARP RESP    Phalanx <= Ovislink_LAN 192.168.0.254      -!- 192.168.0.98
IP/TCP      Phalanx => Ovislink_LAN 192.168.0.98:50001 =>  192.168.0.254:8080 SYN
IP/TCP      Plalanx <= Ovislink_LAN 192.168.0.98:50001 <=  192.168.0.254:8080 SYNACK
IP/TCP      Phalanx => Ovislink_LAN 192.168.0.98:50001 =>  192.168.0.254:8080 ACK
```

After the ARP request, a TCP connection is established with the normal SYN, SYN ACK, ACK process. And all is well.

Now, rather than connecting the modem to my desktop PC, i connect it to the PC that is running pfSense.

**Note:** Previously, i had changed pfSense's LAN IP Address to be `192.168.1.1/16`, rather than `192.168.1.1/24`. This is because my network was already `192.168.0.0/16`.

First thing i do is disable the **"Block private networks"** feature under `Interfaces->WAN`, since my modem's LAN interface is running as `192.168.0.254`. This removes the first firewall entry under `Firewall->Rules` that was blocking all RFC1918 traffic. Next i added a firewall rule:

**Action:** Pass
**Interface:** WAN
**Protocol:** TCP
**Source:** Single host or alias, 192.168.0.254
**Destination:** LAN subnet
**Destination Port Range:** any
**Log Packets:** Yes
**Description:** ADSL Modem

After saving and applying my changes i tried using the `Diagnostics->Ping` feature to ping `192.168.0.254` on the WAN side. It, of course, didn't work.

i thought about it, and it seems to me that i can't just allow TCP packets in on the WAN from `192.168.0.254`, i also need to allow ARP response packets (how else could pfSense find the MAC address of the hardware it's trying to send an IP packet to?). It also occurred to me that i can't say LAN as the destination, because it's actually the WAN interface that's pinging. So i updated the firewall rule to:

**Action:** Pass
**Interface:** WAN
**Protocol:** any
**Source:** Single host or alias, 192.168.0.254
**Destination:** any
**Destination Port Range:** any
**Log Packets:** Yes
**Description:** ADSL Modem

Now when i ping it...doesn't work. No real surprise there.  So i decided to run a packet trace:

**Interface:** WAN
**Host Address:** 192.168.0.254
**Count:** 1
**Level of Detail:** Full

i started the trace, did a ping from `Diagnostics->Ping`, and get...nothing. No ping reply, and no packets in the trace.

So now it occurs to me that just because:

- pfSense is on the `192.168.1.1/16` subet
- my desktop is on the `192.168.0.98/16` subnet
- my server is on the `192.168.0.10/16` subnet

maybe the modem is not on the `/16` subnet. i plug the modem back into my desktop, connect to the web interface and see that it's set for `192.168.0.254/24`. So i reconfigure the modem for `192.168.1.254/24`. i then reconfigure

- my desktop to be `192.168.1.98`,
- the server to be `192.168.1.10`,
- and now the modem is `192.168.1.254`
- in addition to pfSense being `192.168.1.1`.

i reconnect the modem to the pfSense box, try to ping it and i get...no reponse.  i do a packet trace for packets from `192.168.1.254` and i see...none.

So now i'm stumped, and am asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've managed to do what you requested. You will need to add a interface, gateway and a rule to route traffic to that gateway for the IP range of your modem.

So my setup:
Billion router connected to telephone cable - set in bridge mode.
pfsense router connected to billion router via lan cable. pfsense version 2.1.5

pfsense set up to have 3 interfaces:

- WAN - PPPOE over re0 (setup as part of setup wizard)
- LAN - dhcp host over em0 with dhcp assigning IPs between 192.168.1.128 and 192.168.1.192 (setup as part of setup wizard)
- MODEMACCESS - dhcp client over re0 (had to be added manually after setup)

Gateways:

- GW_WAN - interface = WAN ; Gateway IP address = dynamic ; default gateway
- MODEMACCESS_DHCP - interface = MODEMACCESS ; Gateway IP address = dhcp; NOT default gateway

Rules:

- Under WAN i have the usual 2 blocks and a pass all, gatway = default
- Under LAN I have 192.168.1.1/24 source and 192.168.1.1/24 destination lockout rule and a few queue assignment rules from 192.168.1.x to !192.168.1.x, gateway = default
- Under MODEMACCESS source 192.168.1.1/24 to destination 10.0.0.2/24 with gateway MODEMACCESS_DHCP

IPs for devices:

- billion router ip 10.0.0.2
- pfsense LAN ip: 192.168.1.1
- pfsense WAN public IP determined by PPPOE
- pfsense MODEMACCESS IP determined by billion DHCP server

I can access the billion router web gui by typing 10.0.0.2 (or the host name) into any browser on any pc on the LAN network. I can access the internet on any device connected on the LAN network (through the PPPOE connection on pfsense.

Comment: Yes, this works. The ability to add extra arbitrary interfaces was added to pfSense sometime after i asked the question. @getack's answer links to the new pfSense How-To entitled [Accessing modem from inside firewall](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Accessing_modem_from_inside_firewall)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it's possible with DSL...  Can you create a firewall rule with only WAN parameters?  In other words, go to Firewall > Rules > WAN and create the rule there.  Be sure to restrict traffic to not include PPPoE, i.e., LAN > WAN.

Comment: No, the only choices for interfaces are `LAN` or `WAN`.

Comment: i'm going to accept the "not possible" answer. It seems to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your modem router is in bridge mode, and that the pfSense router is setup with the PPPoE Client ID to receive your public IP from the ISP directly. Make sure the router is not in bridge mode, and that its set up as a dhcp server. Then tell pfSense to get its WAN IP by DHCP.

That's really just a guess...

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be similar to what some of the others posted. But I think this (https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Accessing_modem_from_inside_firewall) will answer your question

Answer (score 0):

To set this up you would need a switch to plug the modem into.  The PFSense firewall will plug into that switch with two ports.  One port will show up initially as an OPT port, but you can rename it.  The firewall will use the PPPoE connection as the WAN interface but you can route to the modem over the opt interface.